# iOS app flutter permission to access device

Tags: ios, flutter

I was able to successfully implement permission for android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

I looked through almost all the answers in stackoverflow but did not found a way to do it for ios
I am using VSCode as my IDE . I found that i need to add the permissions for `info.plist` but there is no correct documentation with the relevant code for iOS

Comment: what do you mean by permission to access device ?

Comment: @Mukul normally an app ask for permission no so if you want to access user location you need to request permission how to add it to iOS in flutter

Comment: okay, I have added the answer

Answer (score 0):

*You need to Add these lines of code in your *info.plist* file in the *ios->runner* directory to acess the location permission*

For more info on *location permission*, check this [link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/requesting_authorization_for_location_services)

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

**Note: If after adding the permission you are getting any pods error, then install the pods first in your ios directory,
use these commands to install pods in your flutter project:**

```
cd ios
pod install
```